# Incorrect Graduation Date on Resume - Background check

Tags: resume, careers

So, I had an interview at a company and in my resume I listed by graduation date as 2009. My school operates on a full year basis (September to April) and though I completed by courses on Fall/December 2009, but my convocation was on May/June 2010.

As a result, I officially graduated on 2010 instead of 2009. However, I have always written 2009 as my graduation date and never had issue (I guess no one did a background check before).

This time, I had my interview and later they did a background check and I received email from HR regarding this issue and asking for an explanation.

I wrote an email explaining this situation but after that it has been more than a week and still no response from them. I am really not sure what to expect and not sure if they will decide not to extend me an offer :S

Is there anything I should do?

**Update:** 
Thanks everyone for your response.
I received email from HR that they have decided to pursue with other candidates.

I thought I had it. The Lead Dev said he looks forward to seeing me and was very impressed with my answers.

I guess I need to move on and explore more options in life.

Comment: if you explained it to them properly, as you did here, there's not much more you can do.  maybe they chose not to hire you for a reason unrelated to that issue?  Just keep looking for other jobs, you will find the right one.

Comment: Thanks for response. HR said that they will do a background check and if things works out, they will extend me an offer. However, after background check, the graduation date became an issue.... You could be right that there could be other reasons, but I am not really sure. Otherwise, I don't understand why graduation date is becoming a big issue.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue unless they are pointy headed about it. Why didn't you write your graduation date as June 2010 anyway?

Comment: I started looking for work from Jan 2010, and thus wrote 2009 as my graduation date (without the month). If employers asked which month was my convocation (rarely happened), I said I finished my courses last December but convocation is in upcoming June. Again, no one cared about my graduation dates prior to this position. The reason I didn't write 2010 at that time was to avoid employers having this confusion that I am still a student doing my last term etc. Thats how 2009 stayed on my resume.

Comment: `The reason I didn't write 2010 at that time was to avoid employers having this confusion that I am still a student doing my last term etc.` I guess that's not a confusion anymore since you can now prove that you graduated. Just write June 2010 from now on and be done with it.

Comment: I doubt this is a dealbreaker. Just explain your last class was in 2009 but your graduation ceremony was in 2010.

Comment: It won't even be the date of the ceremony. It is the date conferred, under the seal on the testamur. The OP is correct is describing a course completion date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1) If you still haven't heard back, it might make sense to call or email the person in charge and just confirm that everything's ok, offering help / further explanation if needed. Like the other commenters, I'd honestly be surprised if a minor date mistake make much difference.

2) Fix your CV, now! :) If you prefer to keep 2009 strongly, I guess you could state "finished coursework 2009, official graduation date 2010" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
1) I am emailing HR soon regarding the status.
2) I am putting 2010 from now on to avoid any further problems. I wrote 2009 when I started looking for work from early 2010 (prior to my convocation) to avoid employers having confusion that I was still a student. I honestly didn't knew employers cared so much about convocation date.

Comment: @Sanjay It's probably not so much that employers care about the distinction as that they asked your school for a graduation date and your school considers you to have graduated June 2010

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I should do?

You've already responded to HR and explained the discrepancy, so there's nothing to do here except perhaps check in with HR again and see if they need something more.

But you should immediately update your resume with the 2010 graduation date to avoid this issue going forward.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I received email from HR (updated in my post). I also updated my resume from now on.